# Getting javascript variable value with HTML Agility pack

Tags: javascript, html, variables, html-agility-pack

Is it possible to get a javascript variable value with html agility pack?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var title = "Site title";
var articlesummary = "article summary.";
</script>
```

Is there any way that html agility pack would allow me to get the value of the variable `title` for example?

Comment: Nope. You can try doing a regular expression search in the text to get the value you want.

Comment: Ye...I figured as much. Back to regex from xpath=P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the value of a javascript variable in HTML Agility Pack. You have to use regex.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can do it. HtmlAgilityPack gives you the inner html and you pick your texts&variables by your own way.

For example:

```
htmlDocument.SelectNodes("//script[@language='javascript']");
```

This code will give you the inner text of script tag. After that, you may split the whole text ending with ";".

Comment: splitting using ';' is not safe for example

var lineOne = "Items; item1, item2";
var lineTwo = 1;

as you can see var lineOne... will give you two splits that may affect the result you want to get.

Comment: That is not issue for this question. I answered the question you give an example from out of context of the question bro. Also, in your example ''lineOne should have only one value and you should get the only last ';' of the line! Your example was bad practice.